# Using `Map` how do I write a function that converts an array of farenheit values to celcius?

Tags: javascript

I'm am very new to programming and I am trying to solve a problem where I have to convert an array of Fahrenheit values, to Celsius. Though I am not too sure where to start with `.map` and I would really appreciate some help in understanding how to solve this problem.

This was my first attempt in trying to solve the test problem.

```
function convertTemps(array) {
  return array * (9/5) + 32
}
```

These are the problems I am trying to solve

```
describe('convertTemps', () => {
  it('should convert farenheit to celcius for all temperatures in the array', () => {
    expect(convertTemps([23, 140, 212, 41])).to.deep.equal([-5, 60, 100, 5])
    expect(convertTemps([-58, -22, -4, 14])).to.deep.equal([-50, -30, -20, -10])
    expect(convertTemps([104, 122, 158, 176])).to.deep.equal([40, 50, 70, 80])
  })
})
```

Comment: Here is a typical map example: `const squareNums = nums => nums.map(x => x*x);`. Then e.g. `squareNums([3,5,6])` evaluates to `[9,25,36]`. Does that give you a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've written is the function that should run *for each item in the array*, better known as the **callback** or the **predicate**. All you have to do is move that exact function *into* an `Array.map()`.

Note that your formula for `°F -> °C` is incorrect. The correct formula is `(°F − 32) × 5/9 = °C`

Here's a slightly verbose way that demonstrates simply moving your function *into* the `.map`:

```js
function convertTemps(array) {
  return array.map(                // for every value in the array
    function(temp) {               // run this function
      return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9
    }
  );
}

var array = [23, 140, 212, 41];
var result = convertTemps(array);

console.log(result);
```

If you prefer ES6:

```js
const convertTemps = (array) => array.map(temp => (temp-32) * 5/9);

const array = [23, 140, 212, 41];
const result = convertTemps(array);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @RSchneyer Yeah I saw that - just updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question, I really appreciate it. The way you explained it helped me to understand it a lot better. Thanks again.

Comment: @TylerRoper Your answer was really thorough and your wording was easier for me to understand, so thank you again. These homework questions have been a bit challenging for me, I don't really have experience using some of these array methods, but I am trying to get better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use es6 (arrow functions)

```
function convertTemps(array) {
    return array.map(element => element * (9/5) + 32);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this, I've solved it now!

Answer (score 1):

Map is simple, either pass an inline function describing what to do with each item in the array, or define a separate function and pass it in the the map function

```js
//inline map
function convertTemps(array) {
  return array.map(temp => temp * (9/5) + 32)
}


//external function
function convertTemp(temp) {
  return temp * (9/5) + 32;
}

function convertTemps(array) {
  return array.map(convertTemp)
}
```

Comment: @TylerRoper My bad, copied/pasted my own code without paying attention.  It should be good now, thanks for the catch!

Comment: Thank you by the way for taking the time to help me out!